# A-Star Algorithm Does not work for my program (Pacman)

Tags: c++, path-finding, a-star, pacman

im currently trying to code Pacman in C++. Im doing it in RAD Studio 10.2 (Embarcadero IDE) because we have to use it. I implemented a C++-Source-Code for the Ghost-Pathfinding from the Internet. But it never finds a path.

First things first - this is my the source code (that matters for the problem):

```
static int map[ROWS][COLUMNS] = { {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1},
{ 1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 1 },
{ 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1 },
{ 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1 },
{ 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1 },
{ 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1 },
{ 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1 },
{ 1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 1 },
{ 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1 },
{ 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1 },
{ 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1 },
{ 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1 },
{ 1, 7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 7, 1 },
{ 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1 },
{ 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1 },
{ 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 3, 12, 3, 13, 3, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1 },
{ 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 3, 3, 14, 3, 3, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1 },
{ 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1 },
{ 1, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 1 },
{ 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1 },
{ 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 3, 1, 0, 1, 3, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1 },
{ 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1 },
{ 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 11, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1 },
{ 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1 },
{ 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1 },
{ 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1 },
{ 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1 },
{ 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1 },
{ 1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 1 },
{ 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 }
};

const int n = 60; // horizontal size of the map
const int m = 60; // vertical size size of the map
static int closed_nodes_map[n][m]; // map of closed (tried-out) nodes
static int open_nodes_map[n][m]; // map of open (not-yet-tried) nodes
static int dir_map[n][m]; // map of directions
const int dir = 4; // number of possible directions to go at any position
static int dx[dir] = { 1, 0, -1, 0 };
static int dy[dir] = { 0, 1, 0, -1 };
int Gx, Gy, Px, Py;

using namespace std;

void TForm1::GhostMove(Ghost *ghost) {
    Gx = ((ghost->X)-((ghost->X)%32))/32;
    Gy = ((ghost->Y)-((ghost->Y)%32))/32;

    Px = ((player->X)-((player->X)%32))/32;
    Py = ((player->Y)-((player->Y)%32))/32;
    Label1->Caption = Py;
    string st = pathFind(Gx, Gy, Px, Py);
    UnicodeString str = st.c_str();
}
string pathFind(const int &xStart, const int &yStart,
const int &xFinish, const int &yFinish) {
    static priority_queue<node> pq[2]; // list of open (not-yet-tried) nodes
    static int pqi; // pq index
    static node* n0;
    static node* m0;
    static int i, j, x, y, xdx, ydy;
    static char c;
    pqi = 0;

   // reset the node maps
   for (y = 0; y<m; y++)
   {
       for (x = 0; x<n; x++)
       {
        closed_nodes_map[x][y] = 0;
        open_nodes_map[x][y] = 0;
    }
}

// create the start node and push into list of open nodes
n0 = new node(xStart, yStart, 0, 0);
n0->updatePriority(xFinish, yFinish);
pq[pqi].push(*n0);
open_nodes_map[x][y] = n0->getPriority(); // mark it on the open nodes map

                                          // A* search
while (!pq[pqi].empty())
{
    // get the current node w/ the highest priority
    // from the list of open nodes
    n0 = new node(pq[pqi].top().getxPos(), pq[pqi].top().getyPos(),
        pq[pqi].top().getLevel(), pq[pqi].top().getPriority());

    x = n0->getxPos(); y = n0->getyPos();

    pq[pqi].pop(); // remove the node from the open list
    open_nodes_map[x][y] = 0;
    // mark it on the closed nodes map
    closed_nodes_map[x][y] = 1;

    // quit searching when the goal state is reached
    //if((*n0).estimate(xFinish, yFinish) == 0)
    if (x == xFinish && y == yFinish)
    {
        // generate the path from finish to start
        // by following the directions
        string path = "";
        while (!(x == xStart && y == yStart))
        {
            j = dir_map[x][y];
            c = '0' + (j + dir / 2) % dir;
            path = c + path;
            x += dx[j];
            y += dy[j];
        }

        // garbage collection
        delete n0;
        // empty the leftover nodes
        while (!pq[pqi].empty()) pq[pqi].pop();
        return path;
    }

    // generate moves (child nodes) in all possible directions
    for (i = 0; i<dir; i++)
    {
        xdx = x + dx[i]; ydy = y + dy[i];

        if (!(xdx<0 || xdx>n - 1 || ydy<0 || ydy>m - 1 || map[xdx][ydy] == 1
            || closed_nodes_map[xdx][ydy] == 1))
        {
            // generate a child node
            m0 = new node(xdx, ydy, n0->getLevel(),
                n0->getPriority());
            m0->nextLevel(i);
            m0->updatePriority(xFinish, yFinish);

            // if it is not in the open list then add into that
            if (open_nodes_map[xdx][ydy] == 0)
            {
                open_nodes_map[xdx][ydy] = m0->getPriority();
                pq[pqi].push(*m0);
                // mark its parent node direction
                dir_map[xdx][ydy] = (i + dir / 2) % dir;
            }
            else if (open_nodes_map[xdx][ydy]>m0->getPriority())
            {
                // update the priority info
                open_nodes_map[xdx][ydy] = m0->getPriority();
                // update the parent direction info
                dir_map[xdx][ydy] = (i + dir / 2) % dir;

                // replace the node
                // by emptying one pq to the other one
                // except the node to be replaced will be ignored
                // and the new node will be pushed in instead
                while (!(pq[pqi].top().getxPos() == xdx &&
                    pq[pqi].top().getyPos() == ydy))
                {
                    pq[1 - pqi].push(pq[pqi].top());
                    pq[pqi].pop();
                }
                pq[pqi].pop(); // remove the wanted node

                               // empty the larger size pq to the smaller one
                if (pq[pqi].size()>pq[1 - pqi].size()) pqi = 1 - pqi;
                while (!pq[pqi].empty())
                {
                    pq[1 - pqi].push(pq[pqi].top());
                    pq[pqi].pop();
                }
                pqi = 1 - pqi;
                pq[pqi].push(*m0); // add the better node instead
            }
            else delete m0; // garbage collection
        }
    }
    delete n0; // garbage collection
}
return ""; // no route found
}
```

So as you can see it first creates a map - this looks like this:
(Each Tile is 32*32)

[image: Pacman GUI]

Then for the GhostMoving it tries to find the shortest path to the Player. 
But if click the Button for Testing the result/my teststring/testlabel is "" which means no path got found.

I dont really unterstand this because like in the extern algorithm code from the internet my Obstacles(Walls) are 1 in the map array.

So I dont really see through all this - is it maybe because of the Tilesize?

Thanks for your help

Comment: Have you tried using a debugger?

Comment: You're the best person to figure out what the issue is.  You have the full source code, a running program, a test case that breaks, and a debugger.